# Exception error message not display in springboot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, exception, httpresponse

i try to display simple error massage for the unavailable resource of my service model by extending my class with RuntimeException but didn't display

**TodoService Implementation**

```
@Override
public String retrieveTodoStatusById(Long id) {
    Optional<String> optionalTodo = Optional.ofNullable(todoRepository.findStatusById(id));
    System.out.println("OptionalTodo " +optionalTodo );
    String status = optionalTodo.orElseThrow(TodoNotFoundException::new);
    return  status;
}
```

**TodoNotFoundException**

```
package mang.io.todosrestapi.exceptionhandler;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Todo not available")
public class TodoNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

    public TodoNotFoundException(){
    }

public TodoNotFoundException(String message){
    super(message);
}
```

}

[default error with no message is display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19KSA.png)

Every time i run the exception error message is not display
How can display the error message?

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this line in your application.properties file:

```
server.error.include-message=always
```